Why CompletableFuture don't call API in Spring boot?
I'm making multiple API calls at the same time with CompletableFuture to reduce user waiting time.
Here is my code:
@Async
    public CompletableFuture<CommonDataDTO> commonData() throws JsonProcessingException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<UserDTO[]> completableFutureUser = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return  apiHelper.getEmployee();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                return new UserDTO[0];
            }
        });
        CompletableFuture<ContactDTO[]> completableFutureContact = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return  apiHelper.getTravelAgent();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                return new ContactDTO[0];
            }
        });
        CompletableFuture<CurrencyRateDTO[]> completableFutureCurrency = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> apiHelper.getCurrencyRate("site"));

        return CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureUser, completableFutureContact, completableFutureCurrency).thenApply(v -> {
            return new CommonDataDTO(Arrays.stream(completableFutureUser.join()).toList(), Arrays.stream(completableFutureContact.join()).toList(), Arrays.stream(completableFutureCurrency.join()).toList());
        });
    }


But when I run the above code I get an error message like:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.


I added @EnableAsync to the Application class.
Am I doing something wrong here?
Many thanks
I tried replacing allOf with thenCompine but everything is still the same

It is calling however as it is async it is working on a different thread and you are probably using some request scoped beans which aren't accessible on the spawned threads.

It’s difficult to help you since you didn’t provide a [mre]. Note however that @Async is not needed here, as you are handling asynchronicity yourself. When you use @Async, you should use return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(someResult) and let Spring deal with the supplyAsync() and executor for you. A better approach might thus be to make the 3 apiHelper calls themselves @Async (which could actually fix you problem but I’m not sure), or maybe even better, use asynchronous API’s for your calls, such as the AsyncRestTemplate.
